# Json parse error on api call react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this Ajax request function.

```
export async function fetchAllCoinsPromise() {
  const apiCall = await fetch('https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets');
  const jsonResult = await apiCall.json();

  return jsonResult;
}
```

I call it like this:

```
  const fetchCoins = () => {
fetchAllCoinsPromise()
  .then(res => console.log(111))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('err', err);
    fetchCoins();
  });
 };
```

the reason why I'am doing this recursion is because sometimes I'm getting this strange error: `SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "You"]` and I thought the async recursion would solve the issue and it does but I am not sure if this is the best solution in case of time complexity. Any suggestions please?

Comment: What is the content of the response that fails to parse?

Comment: Its an array of objects containing info about crypto coins such as bitcoin ethereum etc...

Comment: Well the parser is saying it is not valid JSON. Log out what you have before you parse it so you can see the string that is invalid.

Comment: The API seems to output invalid JSON. It doesn’t end it properly.

Comment: @user14587589 I tried the same API to reproduce your code, It works fine as expected. Can you please provide the exact data that breaks the code?

Comment: It sounds like that is the response you are expecting but not necessarily the response you are getting when it fails. The JSON parser is failing because it is not an array of objects. There could be a missing comma or it could be sending back an error message like "You need to authenticate before requesting this resource". Take a look and post the response that causes the actual error.

Comment: @evolutionxbox so you mean I should not parse it I should just keep my recursion since I can not do anything about it ?

Comment: "You exceeded your 200 request(s) rate limit of your FREE plan" TADA>...... not JSON.

Comment: @user14587589 the API is giving you corrupt data. It needs to be fixed by the api author

Comment: @epascarello but I have not even used this api before I just wrote it like 20 minutes ago

Comment: @epascarello plus sometimes it is being called successfully sometimes does not

Comment: They have a rate limit.... you hit it somehow.

Comment: @user14587589 To handle these errors, Please check the `Response Status Code` before phrase the JSON

Comment: @user14587589 this is an issue with the API. I don’t think you can fix this

Comment: The best thing you can do is check for that string. If you have it, you know not to parse it and display an error message. OR pay for an account :)

Comment: @user14587589 If you want more quota, then upgrade the plan, If not reduce unnecessary API calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a filter if you want. It might be a hacky solution but it works.

An example might look like:

```
if(jsonResult.startsWith('Y')){
  console.log("Error: " + jsonResult);
  tryYourCallAgain();
  } else {
  return jsonResult;
  }
```

You could use any filter that would catch the error like typeof, includes, etc. Whatever is best in your case.

Pardon if this code is sloppy as I'm relatively new to Javascript,  but this worked for me in a similar case. Hope it helps!